# Im not able to get my custom font working

Tags: flutter

Im trying to setup my font here: https://github.com/kaspernordkvist/uncut_sans/tree/main/Static

this is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
  fonts:
    - family: UncutSans
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/theme/fonts/UncutSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: lib/theme/fonts/UncutSans-Semibold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: lib/theme/fonts/UncutSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: lib/theme/fonts/UncutSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: lib/theme/fonts/UncutSans-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
```

In my ios emulator everything just looks fine, but on my real device it completely ignores my font weights I just set up. For example:

```
...
TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontFamily: 'UncutSans',
                    color: Theme.colorDarkBodyText,)
...
```

This Text is thin and looks fine on simulator. On my real device it more looks like a font weight of Semibold 600.

Whats missing here?

EDIT: Folder Structure (Screenshot I made when I tried to add the variable type of the font. It doesnt make any difference using the variable font and update pubspec.yaml or choose the single ttfs.)

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure?

Comment: updated the folder structure, but like i said the font is being applied, its the weights which are getting ignored on real device only

Comment: You defined path like lib/theme/fonts/UncutSans-Regular.ttf but in your folder your font name is Uncut-Sans-Variable.tff so how you can access the font and you don't have necessary fonts in your fonts folder..

Comment: If you solve your font name so may be it's works fine :}

Comment: What is the status of your problem?

Comment: i fixed it, the error im facing has something to do not with the font itself, its about the ios settings of my real device. i have checked bold text for example as default and it affects my flutter apps font. its irrelevant which font im using.